# Cursor SQL database query with multiple selectionArgs for each selection

Tags: android, sql, android-cursor

I would like to query a database with a specific reference number + either "0" or "3". My below code returns odd results. What would be the correct way to query this.

```
cursor = db.query(TABLE_PAPER, new String[] {KEY_PAPER_ID,

                KEY_PAPER_AMOUNT,
                KEY_PAPER_DATE,
                KEY_PAPER_REFERENCE,
                KEY_PAPER_PAID},KEY_PAPER_REFERENCE + "=?" + " AND " + KEY_PAPER_PAID + "=?" + " OR " + KEY_PAPER_PAID + "=?",
        new String[]{String.valueOf(rowId), "0", "3"},
        null, null, "date DESC");
```

Comment: what is the "odd result"?,can u please elaborate it or specify the expected results and observed results?

Answer (score 0):

You said specific reference number + "1" or "3".But when you write the selection query you pass "0" instead of "1", here

```
 cursor = db.query(TABLE_PAPER, new String[] {KEY_PAPER_ID,
            KEY_PAPER_AMOUNT,
            KEY_PAPER_DATE,
            KEY_PAPER_REFERENCE,
            KEY_PAPER_PAID},KEY_PAPER_REFERENCE + "=?" + " AND " + KEY_PAPER_PAID + "=?" + " OR " + KEY_PAPER_PAID + "=?",
    new String[]{String.valueOf(rowId), "1", "3"},
    null, null, "date DESC");
```

you should pass "1" in query instead of "0".

Comment: Sorry I have edited the post. It was meant to say "0"